# Should I put a paper I'm not proud of on Arxiv?

Tags: computer-science, arxiv

I recently wrote a paper that was accepted as a workshop paper in a conference.

The truth is, I was pretty surprised it was accepted - I wrote it in a matter of weeks and there isn't a lot of novelty in it, it just takes some known techniques, mixes them together slightly, and does a lot of experimental analysis that, on close inspection, don't present anything that insightful. If push comes to shove, I can't really defend anything I did as relevant, and if I didn't desperately need more publications to graduate I don't think I would have ever submitted it.

My question is, should I put it on Arxiv? I'm having a hard time gauging how big a deal it is to put up a paper I'm not especially proud of. There's nothing egregiously wrong with it, though I think someone could plausibly accuse the analysis of reading too much signal into noise. On the other hand, it was accepted by 3 reviewers, so maybe I'm being too harsh on myself?

Comment: Does the workshop have published proceedings? If yes, it is already available publicly anyway.

Comment: Just do it. Nothing bad will happen and it can only be good, I think.

Comment: Ask someone who has read it.

Comment: Also, "don't present anything that insightful" and "reading too much signal into noise" don't seem to be the same thing — does the paper just lack novelty of results (in which case it may still be a useful contribution in other ways), or does it make unsound conclusions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are under no obligation to put anything on arXiv or equivalent.

In particular, if this was a bit of "make-work", that won't really help anyone else (beyond your own paper-count), you can indeed take the viewpoint that it's better to *not* clutter up the internet with pointless things.

On another hand, perhaps you misjudge the potential of what you wrote. For that matter, there is lots of crap not only on the internet but also on arXiv. You *could* take the viewpoint that putting it on arXiv is a sort of honest expression of your work (even if you didn't accomplish anything heroic in this interval).